# regular expression match all strings that start with T

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, google-chrome-extension

I need a little help in writing a regular expression.

I need to find all sub-strings of strings that start with `T.` and end with `.` (in this case, those sub-strings are numbers). Those strings have to be unique.

For example:

```
    T.220431.2 = 1.16363965404949
    T.220431.1 = 1.16363965404949
    T.3923331.2 = 0.335752950772576
    T.3923331.1 = 0.335752950772576
    T.4125531.2 = 0.335752950772576
    T.4125531.1 = 0.335752950772576
```

I want to get an array {220431, 392331, 4124431}

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT:** Since I am getting a ton of negative votes, just wanted to say that i did try to use `^[T]\.[0-9]+[\.]` but it did not work for me. Go easy on me guys, I am just trying to learn here...

Comment: I cant see a reason to have brackets around `T`.

Comment: I tried it without brackets at first but it did not work, so I thought maybe adding the brackets will fix the problem. Btw thanks for answering and not down-voting me :)

Comment: `var regex=/\bT\.(\d+)\./g, match, result=[];while((match=regex.exec(string))){if(result.indexOf(match[1])==-1)result.push(match[1]);}/*Now your list is available in result*/` (voted to close as Too Localized; edit: note: Stack Overflow added an invisibile zero-width character in the previous code block, exercise for the reader to remove it in order to get valid code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is `/\bT\.(\d+)\./g`. The reason why my regex didn't work is that I didn't take into account the white spaces at the beginning of the string.

Anyways, after using this regex got the substring with the required numbers, and used join() to merge everything together.

Thank you Rob W for answering.

Answer (score 1):

remove the $ from regex? obviously you arent matching whole line.

Comment: try http://regexpal.com/ to test various regexes

Comment: Thanks for the link and tip

Comment: you are right "$" shouldn't be there, not sure why I added it. With that said, the regular expression still did not work and I am still getting NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Like with any regular expressions, there are infinite possible solutions to get the thing flying. Look for the `parseValues(...)` function in main.js below.

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/rYSwx/) is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/rYSwx/

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='output'></div>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
(function (document) {
    function parseValues(values) {
        var results = [];
        var regex = /T\.(\d+)?.*/;
        var len = values.length;
        var i;
        var result;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result = values[i].replace(regex, '$1');
            if (result) {
                if (results.indexOf(result) < 0) {
                    results.push(result);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    };

    function main() {
        var values = [
            'T.220431.2 = 1.16363965404949',
            'T.220431.1 = 1.16363965404949',
            'T.3923331.2 = 0.335752950772576',
            'T.3923331.1 = 0.335752950772576',
            'T.4125531.2 = 0.335752950772576',
            'T.4125531.1 = 0.335752950772576'
        ];
        var results = parseValues(values);
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var len = results.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            output.innerHTML += results[i] + '<br/>';
        }
    };

    main();

})(document);
```